# Typescript object type comparison

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compare object types in typescript.

Is there a way to pass a type as a parameter and compare? something like the following C# code in typescript?

```
class A
{
}
class B
{
}
void Main()
{
    TypeTest(typeof(B));
}
void TypeTest(Type t)
{
    if (t == typeof(A))
    {
        ...
    }
    else (t == typeof(B))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript types are erased at runtime, however maybe you could make do with a perfectly vanilla javascript feature: prototypes.

```
class A {}
class B {}

function typeTest(prototype: any) {
    if (prototype === A.prototype) {
        //
    } else if (prototype === B.prototype) {
        //
    }
}

typeTest(A.prototype)
```